# Unable to send fax "Err_Call_Rejected"

Tags: linux, freeswitch, pbx, fax, fusionpbx

am trying to send fax from fusionpbx  but whenever i click on send button i get this error "Err_Call_Rejected" i check everything my gateway and IP in access control everything is ok but still getting this error am using flowroute for SIP, anything would be appreciated 
Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you see any error on freeswitch cli ? you can check debug logs of cli, to understand why it was rejected.

Comment: Thanks sandeesh for replying i tried to check logs but am unable to understand what exactly wrong because am new in this and trying to learn. Can you please what configuration are required for fusionpbx to send fax? @SadeeshRadhakrishnan